# UML - Class Diagram relationships

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Regarding the multiplicity between classes, I have seen 1..1 and 1 in the same textbook without clarifying the difference. What is the difference between 1..1 and 1 ?
Are they same and used interchangeably?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

They are semantically equivalent according to [Version 2.5 of OMG's UML standard, see section 7.5.4.1](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/PDF)

What follows are relevant quotes from that section.

> The multiplicity bounds may be shown in the format:
>   `<lower-bound> ‘..’ <upper-bound>`

> If the lower bound is equal to the upper bound, then an alternate
>   notation is to use a string containing just the upper bound. For
>   example, “1” is semantically equivalent to “1..1” multiplicity.